# Working with multiple branches in ASP .NET

Tags: iis, asp.net

I've seen several other posts similar to this (namely https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237/solutions-for-working-with-multiple-branches-in-asp-net) but there are several issues that I have that seem to be different than other similar posts.

I have an ASP .NET application that uses a virtual directory off of localhost. There are several spots in the code where I need to reference the name of the virtual directory so the virtual directory needs to be in place and named correctly in order for it to work. I'm also using my httpd.conf file to format my URLs to avoid cluttered querystrings.

That being said, I just published my application and now need to create a branched environment for bug-fixes whenever there is a bug in the live code and I don't want to upload the dev code.

The trouble is that I need to be able to easily run my branched code parallel to my dev code without needing to do a bunch of work with IIS and config files every time I want to load in my branched code. The drawbacks are that the parallel environment needs to have the virtual directory in place and work with the same httpd.conf (for URL formatting).

I don't think Cassini would work because I need SSL and of course...the httpd.conf and the virtual directories would need to still be in place.

The perfect solution in my mind would be to run a parallel website to localhost with the same httpd.conf and the same virtual directory...but I'm running XP Pro and they don't "do" multiple websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you bypass SSL for development?  That would allow you to use Cassini for each project.

If you're using IIS on XP (i.e. 1 site only), how about putting each project in a subfolder marked as an application?  You'll likely need some modifications to your httpd.conf to accommodate your dev and production environment.

Of course upgrading to Win 7 is another option.

Yet another option is to script an IIS setting swap using adsutil.vbs.  As you switch projects, just run a batch file configured to repoint the paths and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with the last approach you mentioned. But I couldn't find my adsutil (I read that SP3 deletes it) so I wrote a script of my own using this thread as a resource: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371207/can-i-automate-creating-a-net-web-application-virtual-directory-in-iis-5

Comment: Excellent.  Glad you got a working solution.  The script on that link is a good one too.